# How to find script directory in an included shell script

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, tcsh

We now to find the directory of a shell script using `dirname` and `$0`, but this doesn't work when the script is inluded in another script.

Suppose two files `first.sh` and `second.sh`:

/tmp/first.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
. "/tmp/test/second.sh"
```

/tmp/test/second.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $0
```

by running `first.sh` the second script also prints `first.sh`. How the code in `second.sh`  can find the directory of itself? (Searching for a solution that works on bash/csh/zsh)

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @janos: No, janos, it is possible, see my answer

Comment: @IgorChubin Awesome! I left that comment so somebody will ping me back ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no solution that will work equally good in all flavours of shells.

In `bash` you can use `BASH_SOURCE`:

```
$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")
```

Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/1.sh
. /tmp/sub/2.sh
$ cat /tmp/sub/2.sh
echo $BASH_SOURCE
$ bash /tmp/1.sh 
/tmp/sub/2.sh
```

As you can see, the script prints the name of `2.sh`,
although you start `/tmp/1.sh`, that includes `2.sh` with the `source` command.

I must note, that this solution will work only in `bash`. In Bourne-shell (`/bin/sh`) it is impossible.

In csh/tcsh/zsh you can use `$_` instead of `BASH_SOURCE`.

Comment: This is bash specific. I mentioned in question that I searching for a solution that works on bash/csh/zsh

Comment: And note that I used `/bin/sh` as interpreter

Comment: I've note in the answer that it will only work in bash. In bourne-shell it is impossible.

Comment: @TahaJahangir: You have written that you look for solution for tcsh/zsh/bash; I've provided you with it. My solution will work in bash/tcsh/zsh.

Comment: In bash We can use `${VAR:-DEFAULT}` construct to use another variable if $VAR is not defined, but this not works in tsch/zsh. Also $_ not works in `sh`!. Can you modify you solution to work on csh and bash, or sh?

Comment: @TahaJahangir: I know, that `$_` will not work in Bourne shell. I've written it. As far as I know there are no way to find that name of included script in Bourne shell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42730/discussion-between-taha-jahangir-and-igor-chubin)